# Django Template URLs and NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, templates, url

I'm just starting out with Django and having some issues with URLs in templates. If I have my template like this the link works fine but will anger the Django puritans, apparently:

```
<h1><a href="addNums">New Message</a></h1>
```

but if I put it like this, as the tutorial suggests, I get a NoReverseMatch error

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'addNums' %}">New Message</a></h1>
```

I have the urls set up as so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('addNums/', add) 
]
```

What is going on here? What is the difference in semantics between the two methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to mention the url name

**try this**

```
app_name = 'my-app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('addNums/', add, name='my-url') 
]
```

in template

```
<h1><a href="{% url 'my-app:my-url' %}">New Message</a></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `{% url ... %}` looks for a path with the *name* `'addNums'`, so you should provide a name in your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('addNums/', add, name='addNums') 
]
```

The main idea of `{% url ... %}` is to derive the URL, such that, if you later change your mind on the path, the generated URL will change as well.